# JavaFX Webview not able to change the url

Tags: java, swing, webview

I am developing a java swing application and have embedded the webview component of javafx following the oracle tutorial simplebrowser, the url is loading fine .How do i make webview show a different url during run time ? I tried calling the loadURL method below with a different url , but it does not work , have also tried to create a new ReloaURL method to do the job , still does not work , any help here is appreciated.

```
        private void initComponents(String FilePath) {
        createScene();
        loadURL("file:///"+FilePath);

        }

        private void createScene() {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


            WebView view = new WebView();
            engine = view.getEngine();
            jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));


            }
        }); 
        }

        public void loadURL(final String url) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            String tmp = toURL(url);

            if (tmp == null) {
                tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
            }

            engine.load(tmp);
            }
        });
        }

        public void ReloadURL(final String url) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            String tmp = toURL(url);

            if (tmp == null) {
                tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
            }
            //engine.load(tmp);
            view.getEngine().load(tmp);
            }   
        });
        }

        private static String toURL(String str) {
        try {
            return new URL(str).toExternalForm();
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
            return null;
        }
        }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: thanks for looking into this , did a workaround by making it to read the url from a textfield which had a listener hooked on to it.